# Getting protected information from an object in PHP

Tags: php, class, object

I'm pretty new to PHP and am trying to understand how to access properties of objects.

I have a class called `Dog` and in it's class I have the following:

```
class Dog extends Resource {
    protected $_data = array(
        'dog_id' => array(
             'type' => Resource::PROPERTY_TYPE_INTEGER, 
             'value' => null
         ), 
         'owner_id' => array(
             'type' => Resource::PROPERTY_TYPE_INTEGER, 
             'value' => null
         )        
    )
}
```

Now I'm trying to use this data in a controller.

```
$drm = DogResouceModel::create(); 
$fido = array_values($drm->find($dog_id))[0];
```

This works and I get the desired `Dog` object as `$fido`.  How would I get to the `owner_id`?  Using XDebug in Eclipse I can see that the values are all attached to `$fido`, I just can't seem to figure out how to get to them.  I've tried things along the lines of:

```
$owner_id = $fido["_data"]["owner_id"];  
$owner_id = $fido->_data->owner_id;
```

Comment: in class `Dog` add a public getter (`public function getOwnerId() { return $this->_data['owner_id']['value']; }`

Comment: it's protected. you can't access it from "outside". you'd need to mod the class to put in a method to retrieve it for you. e.g. RTFM: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Comment: @MarcB that makes sense, but why I can I see the information connected to `$fido`?

Comment: because you're using a debugger, which can dig inside php's innards and bypass the protections. debuggers would be useless otherwise. but in normal operations, `protected` and `private` data would be unreachable/invisible from outside

Comment: @tibsar: cf last bit in my answer, I've updated it to explain why you can see the values in Xdebug, but can't access them directly

Comment: BTW: +1 for using Xdebug, even though you're new to PHP

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem It wasn't fun to set up, but it's been a life saver!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The common way to do this is to implement getter/setter methods:

```
class Dog extends Resource
{
    protected $data = [];//initialize as before (no need for the underscore)

    public function getOwnerId()
    {
        return $this->data['owner_id']['value'];
    }
    //setter example
    public function setOwnerId($id)
    {
        if (!is_numeric($id)) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('Owner id is numeric');
        }
        $this->data['owner_id']['value'] = (int) $id;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

The rational behind this is that getters and setters allow you to validate data, normalize it and define, in greater levels of detail, how an object should behave if, for example, a value isn't available (ie: if owner_id is null, you might want to throw an exception in some cases).

The fact that you can see them in an XDebug session is simply because the *data* is set, and XDebug allows you to inspect the state of all objects. It doesn't follow the rules of inheritance in that it can see all values that are in play, regardless of them being private, protected or public. Xdebug is a PHP extension, it's written in C and sits on top of the Zend engine (the PHP internals), it is not bound by the syntax, grammar or whatever else that is part of PHP.

Think of Xdebug as an MRI scanner or X-ray machine: it allows you to see what is going on underneath the skin. It's a tool doctors use, like debuggers are tools that developers use to diagnose problems.

Looking at what you've tried, even if `$data` *were* public, neither approach would've worked:

```
$owner_id = $fido["_data"]["owner_id"];
```

The problem here is that this plies that `$fido` is an array, or an object that implements the `ArrayAccess` interface. We don't know what `Resource` looks like, so maybe it does (more on that later).

```
$owner_id = $fido->_data->owner_id;
```

This is closer to what you could do if `_data` were public, but only if its value were an object, too (which it isn't, it's an array).

So what should you write if `$_data` were public? Well simply this:

```
$ownerId = $fido->_data['owner_id']['value'];//to get the value
$ownerIdArray = $fido->_data['owner_id'];//will be an array
```

If `Resource` implements the `ArrayAccess` interface, chances are it relies on the `$_data` property, and returns the values for each key. In that case you might be able to write:

```
$ownerId = $fido['owner_id']
```

or even iterate over the object:

```
foreach ($fido as $propery => $value) {
    //do stuff
}
```

Check the PHP documentation for details on [the `ArrayAccess` interface](http://php.net/ArrayAccess)

Comment: *I'm pretty new to PHP*, this says to me that the OP doesn't know about PHP's exceptions, do you think it's a bit much for this question?

Comment: @SamSwift웃: Perhaps, but the OP is using inheritance, and Xdebug, that tells me the OP is quite willing to learn how to do things properly. I added the exception because it's a habit of mine, and left it there in case it prompts the OP (or somebody else) to read up on the subject

Comment: That makes sense! Thank's for the explanation on this matter :)

Answer (score 1):

Because `_data` is protected, it's not possible to directly access it from outside the `Dog` or `Resource` classes. Instead, you should add an accessor to either `Dog` or `Resource` (as appropriate) that retrieves the requested data.

```
class Dog extends Resource {
    public function getOwerId() {
        return $this->_data['owner_id']['value'];
    }
}
```

You could also force `_data` to be accessible by hacking it using the Reflection API, but that's *really* not something you should be doing on production code.

Comment: You really shouldn't implement a method on `Resource` that reads from a property that is defined in `Dog`. That's just asking for trouble.

Comment: Yes, true. That was making an assumption that was possibly unwarranted.

Answer (score 1):

**OOP Programming PHP**

You are using OOP, grats dude (or dudette :P)!

PHP is great for this, however it has it's limitations, for example, accessing properties.
You have used `protected $_data = array( /* your info */ );`, this means it is only visible to the class and any class that `extends` this.

For example, if you had these classes:

```
class Foo 
{
    protected $foo = "Foo";
}

class Bar extends Foo
{
    private $bar = "bar";
}
```

You could add a function, as such:

```
public function getFooBar()
{
    return "{$this->foo} {$this->bar}";
}
```

Inside the `Bar` class, that simply returns the value of `$foo` and `$bar`, meaning if you use this code:

```
$bar = new Bar();
print $bar->getFooBar(); // prints "Foo bar"
```

But you cannot do this:

```
print $bar->foo;
print $bar->bar;
```

These are seen as `private` properties of the `Bar` class and as such cannot be accessed outside of the class.

When you use `protected` or `private` properties, if you need to access them outside the class, create a get function for them.

**Why does the debugger show the private and protected properties?**

When using a debugger such as XDebug, it is designed to show all properties within an object, this is so that the person debugging (you), can see exactly what's in an object and be able to create some sort of functionality to access this if needed. Without this, debugging tools would be rather useless.

I hope this helps you out :P

Comment: Great, but that doesn't address the actual question: why the values are visible in Xdebug, but OP can't access them (ie why a debugger can seemingly break the rules of data encapsulation et all). BTW: I know it's personal preference, but this: `"{$this->foo} {$this->bar}";`<-- looks awful IMO

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem, cheers for that, I shall add an edit :P to me using the curly syntax when using properties/variables inside a string makes sense to me, just what I prefer :P

Comment: I know it's personal preference, in the same way that I prefer `sprintf('%s %s', $this->foo, $this->bar);` or simple concatenation (`return $this->foo . '  ' . $this->bar`). PHP's curly syntax trips me up, I keep finding myself reverting to bash-style variable expansion (ie `echo "${varname}"`)... that's probably why I don't like it